# Сортировка двумерного массива чисел Java Script

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Помогите написать функцию, которая будет сортировать по возрастанию этот двумерный массив. Заранее спасибо!

```
function getRandomInt(min, max){//Функция для генерации случайного числа
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}


function matrixArray(rows,columns){ //Функция, которая создаёт двумерный массив
  var arr = new Array();
  for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
    arr[i] = new Array();

        for(var j=0; j<columns; j++){
          arr[i][j] = getRandomInt(0, 100);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

var myMatrix = matrixArray(7,5); 
console.log(myMatrix);

Изначально хотел через: 


     function compareNumbers(a, b) {
          return a - b;
        }
```

и вызывал:

```
var myMatrix = matrixArray(7,5); 
console.log(myMatrix.sort(compareNumbers));
```

но не вышло, видимо она сортирует лишь одномерный массив

Comment: то есть он должен сортировать внутри строк и внутри столбцов?

Comment: Лишь внутри строк

Comment: Какой результат сортировки ожидается для массива `[[3, 2], [1, 4]]` и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле, вам не много-то и осталось. Просто вместе самого массива, сортируете его элементы ( которые сами являются массивами )

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max){//Функция для генерации случайного числа
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function matrixArray(rows,columns){ //Функция, которая создаёт двумерный массив
  var arr = new Array();
  for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
    arr[i] = new Array();

        for(var j=0; j<columns; j++){
          arr[i][j] = getRandomInt(0, 100);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

var myMatrix = matrixArray(7,5);
myMatrix.forEach(row => row.sort(compareNumbers));
console.log(myMatrix);
```